# Action triggered when two buttons are tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

How can I trigger an action in Swift when two buttons are pressed simultaneously? My code below triggers the action when one button is pressed. I would like this action to trigger only if both buttons are tapped.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.leftButtonClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  }

  func leftButtonClicked() {
      // Do something
  }
}
```

Do I need to use UIGestureRecognizer or can this be done with the addTarget action above? How would the code look like?

Comment: I found this, hope it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039115/two-button-simultaneous-press-input

Comment: Thanks, that post was the answer in Objective C and I have translated it to Swift, which I will post in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comment above I have now written the solution in Swift and it turns out to be very simple:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

  @IBAction func touchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if leftButton.touchInside && rightButton.touchInside {
      print("Two buttons pressed")
}
```

I removed the clutter that is not relevant for the solution.